Rails 7: Upload image to rich text area did not show
I follow this video in the homepage of ruby on rails: https://rubyonrails.org/ . These are my steps
rails new demo
rails generate scaffold post title:string content:text
rails db:migrate
rails server
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/posts
http://localhost:3000/posts/1
http://localhost:3000/posts/1/edit
http://localhost:3000/posts/new

File D:\2024_04_29\demo\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.simplecss.org/simple.min.css">
  <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>

http://localhost:3000/posts.json
http://localhost:3000/posts/2.json
Validate
File D:\2024_04_29\demo\app\models\post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :title
end

rails console
rails c
Post.first
Post.create! title:”From the console”, content: “Nice!”
Post.where(created_at: Time.now.all_day).to_sql

Post.where(created_at: Time.now.all_day)


irb(main):008> Post.where(created_at: Time.now.yesterday.all_day)

irb(main):008> Post.where(created_at: Time.now.yesterday.all_day).to_sql

rails action_text:install
bundle
rails db:migrate

File D:\2024_04_29\demo\app\models\post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :title
    has_rich_text :content
end

File D:\2024_04_29\demo\app\views\posts\_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: post) do |form| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% post.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :title, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :content, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>


I checked database

source code: https://github.com/donhuvy/rails7demo
Why my images did not show? How to fix it?

The problem is that you create column posts.content as text datatype
Action Text don't need column in the model tables. Action Text is some kind of the model that associates with other models using polymorphic associations by record_id and record_type columns
Firstly you need to create (if not exists) table, styles and partials for Action Text with command
bin/rails action_text:install

I don't prefer rails generators, but your first command should be
bin/rails g scaffold post title:string content:rich_text

(rich text, not just text)
This command will not create new column, just add has_rich_text notation to the model, views etc.
You need drop posts.content column
Also note that in case you convert the images, you will need system library (libvips by default)
Read more:
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html
